# Magento: admin - product search filter

Tags: magento, admin, filtering

I'm working for a client who owns a Magento-based store. It's chock full of products, but the names of said products are a bit messy. He did not stick to one naming convention but used different conventions throughout the years. So whenever he looks up something using the Name filter in the Admin -> Manage Products section, the results leave a lot to be desired.

So I was wondering if there's a way to make the filtering algorithm a bit more lax, specifically in regards to word order. Because if you have a product with a name like '*word1 word2 word3*' and you search '*word1 word3*' that products doesn't appear in the results.

Any hint would be appreciated. Cheers!

**AUG 28 UPDATE:** My search led me to the class *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid*, and more precisely to its protected method *_addColumnFilterToCollection()*. In here you have the *$cond* variable, which if you print out it gives you something like this:

> Array ([like] => Zend_Db_Expr Object([_expression:protected] => '%search term%' ))

Here if I could intercept that search term and make it into '*%search%term%*' before it gets submitted to the *Zend_Db_Expr* object I'd probably solve my problem. So, any ideas?

Comment: I think a 'search within' feature would be easier to implement - so you can narrow down results... fuzzy search would require reformatting tables to MyISAM fulltext or even utilizing a tool like Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a solution for this problem. Please note I have not tested this too much, just on my local test magento. So problems may arise.

Our work class is Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid, found in 'app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php'. You should copy this file in 'app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php', as to not overwrite core classes.

Now, in that file go to the function named _addColumnFilterToCollection. In here, delete everything inside the '} else {' statement and replace with:

```
$cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
if ($field == "name" && isset($cond)) {
$filterOrig = $cond['like'];
$filterReplaced = str_replace(" ", "%", $filterOrig);
$newZendDbExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr($filterReplaced);
$modifCond = array('like'=>$newZendDbExpr);
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $modifCond);
} else if ($field && isset($cond)) {
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
}
```

The '$cond' variable is the key here. If you print it you get something like:

```
Array([like] => Zend_Db_Expr Object([_expression:protected] => '%filter term%'));
```

That code snippet basically intercepts the filter term that's passed to the Zend_Db_Expr object, passes it through a str_replace() to replace any whitespace with a '%' wildcard and then sends it back to the object.

So now if you have a product with a name like 'word1 word2 word3' and search filter by term 'word1 word3' you will get proper results. I am open to suggestions, this might not be the best approach. I'll update after properly testing this. Cheers!

**SEP 06 UPDATE**: Well, after some live testing, results are good and exactly what I wanted when. It seems there is no negative performance impact either.

And the interesting fact is that this little modification applies to filtering in every place where you have a product grid in the admin interface (for example when creating a new order manually and you click Add Products, or in the Manage Categories -> whatever category -> Category Products tab)

**SEP 06 UPDATE 2**: There is an issue. If you're in the Orders grids and try to filter by status it throws an error. I need to make this filter only apply to the Name field. Any ideas?

**SEP 06 UPDATE 3**: I revised the script to only apply to the Name field of Product grids. Now there are no conflicts with filter products by visibility or orders by status etc.

Comment: @Eugen Pop : really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

That would require coding a custom module having some complexity.

The expectation, that filtering for `word1 word3` should at least return a subset of the matches, that filtering by `word1 word2 word3` does return, is based on the false assumption that Magento does perform `OR` searches for this grid filter.

This is *not* the case. Magento does not perform `OR`, but `LIKE` searches in this case.

That also explains, why the result sets of a

```
LIKE name = '%word1 word2 word3%'
```

usually *never** can match the result set of a

```
LIKE name = '%word1 word3%'
```

I think `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareCollection()` will be the minimum that needs to be overridden by your code, to get you started.

Good luck!

---

<sub>* except `word2 == word3`, of course</sub>

Comment: Since Magento performs a LIKE search, I am wondering if it would be possible to intercept the filtering term inserted in the filter box and change it before submit to add a '%' wildcard instead of a whitespace. Like if you inserted "word1 word3" in the filter box it would change it to "word1 % word3". This would yield better results I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'filter_condition_callback' to any grid in Magento. Create a rewrite for Magento product grid and add this param to 'name' field. Like

```
$this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filter_name_callback'),
        ));
```

And then determine filter_name_callback method in the same class.
Something like this:

```
protected function filter_name_callback($collection, $column)
    {
        $names = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        $namesArray = explode(' ', $names);
        $cond = array();
        foreach ($namesArray as $item)
        {
            $cond[] = 'main_table.name LIKe %'.$item.'%';
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->where("(".implode(' OR ', $cond).")");
    }
```

The code was not tested, the example is simple, but I think you understand the idea ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To do wildcard % search for a given column, and if you can override the core `Grid.php`, then you can do something like this in your grid class:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();   

    // assuming the column is 'name' for product name in the product grid
    $this->getColumn('name')->setFilterConditionCallback([$this, 'allowWildcardInFilter']);
    ...
}

/**
 * Allow wildcard % in column search
 */
public function allowWildcardInFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if ($value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        if ($field = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex()) {
            /**
             * @var $helper Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4
             */
            $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
            $likeExpression = $helper->addLikeEscape($value, [
                'position' => 'any',
                'allow_string_mask' => true
            ]);
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, ['like' => $likeExpression]);
        }
    }
}
```